# Devise not working with rails. (Undefined local variable or method `‘devise’' for Gemfile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, gemfile

I've added gem 'devise' to the gem file after having done gem install devise.

I get the following error when I run bundle install:

`Undefined local variable or method`‘devise’' for Gemfile.`

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'mysql'


gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

gem ’devise’
```

when I remove the gem devise bundle install works, otherwise I get the error undefined local variable or method devise for Gemfile.

Comment: the syntax is fine on the Gemfile. Just the bundle install wouldn't work and I got the error that said undefined local variable or method for Gemfile.

Comment: remove 'devise' and try again. please post the contents of gemfile and the error log.

Comment: Please add your whole gemfile to the question.

Comment: It works without the gem devise, but I wanted to use devise authentication for rails for which i had to add the gem devise to the gem file.

Comment: The answer below is correct - you have backticks instead of single quotes around `devise`

Comment: I've added a snippet of the Gemfile to the question.

Comment: I'm definite I've use the single quote key and not the back tick.

Comment: ` - backtick ' - single quote

Comment: Sorry, maybe I used the wrong term - but in anycase it looks wrong as you see after my edit to display your file in a codeblock - I didn't make any other changes other than hitting ctrl-k around the Gemfile contents.  Maybe it's a problem in your editor.

Comment: I typed the rest of the gem file which includes a bootstrap gem and others using the same editor, but yes i did notice the quotation mark looked off, but it is the single quote.

Comment: Well, the single quote looks fine now and bundle install works, after I typed the quotation mark while pressing the ctrl key. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using TextEdit on Mac OSX, you may want to make sure that under your preferences Smart quotes is not checked. This will update your apostrophes and quotes into what is "typographically appropriate" according to the program. You're typing a single tick mark / prime mark (U+2027) and its converting it to a an apostrophe (U+2032). Alternately, you can hold the ctrl key while pressing the quote mark to get the non-slanted tick mark. I just spent 20 minutes with this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your Gemfile  should look like below

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'devise'
```

Comment: It does look like this.

Comment: I'm definite I've used the single quote key and not the back tick. 
      
` - backtick ' - single quote on the Gemfile it is gem 'device'.